# How to perform a R untidy sum?

Tags: r, string, sum, match, tidy

**Update**

I have untidy data that looks like the example `df2`.

```r
df2 = data.frame(label = c("C360", "C360~C183", "C157~C360", "C183", "C157", "C157~C183", "C195~C183"), 
                 values = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))
> df2
      label values
1      C360     10
2 C360~C183     11
3 C157~C360     12
4      C183     13
5      C157     14
6 C157~C183     15
7 C195~C183     16
```

I need to sum partial matches that include the letters in different positions, so that I will the following desired output:

```r
  string sum
1   C360  33
2   C183  55
3   C157  41
4   C195  16
```

---

**Old**

```r
df1 = data.frame(label = c("a", "a.1", "2.a", "b", "c"), 
                 values = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
> df1
  label values
1     a     10
2   a.1     11
3   2.a     12
4     b     13
5     c     14
```

Expected output:

```r
   label sum
1      a  33
2      b  13
3      c  14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New**

```r
stack(setNames(strsplit(df2$label, "~"), df2$values)) |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |>
  `colnames<-`(names(df2)) |>
  aggregate(values ~ label, sum)

  label values
1  C157     41
2  C183     55
3  C195     16
4  C360     33
```

Data:

```r
df2 = data.frame(label = c("C360", "C360~C183", "C157~C360", "C183", "C157", "C157~C183", "C195~C183"), 
                 values = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))
```

---

**Old**

For `df1`, you might consider

```r
aggregate(df1$values, list(letter = gsub("[^a-z]", "", df1$label)), sum)

  letter  x
1      a 33
2      b 13
3      c 14
```

where the appropriate regex (something more concrete than `"[^a-z]"`) depends on your `letter` (`labels`) column.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That would solve for letters. But what if I have more complex strings, like "C360" for example? In "C360-C120" and "C240-C360" and I want to sum "C360"?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the example data.

Answer (score 3):

For your updated example, you can use `tidyr::separate_rows()`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  separate_rows(label, sep = "~") %>%
  group_by(string = label) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(values))
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#   string   sum
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 C157      41
# 2 C183      55
# 3 C195      16
# 4 C360      33
```

For your original example, you can use `stringr::str_extract()` to extract and group by letters:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(letter = str_extract(label, "[a-z]")) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(values))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   letter   sum
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 a         33
# 2 b         13
# 3 c         14
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(letter = str_remove_all(label, "[^[:alpha:]]")) %>% 
  summarise(.by = letter, sum = sum(values))

# ----------
> df2
  letter sum
1      a  33
2      b  13
3      c  14
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That would solve for letters. But what if I have more complex strings, like "C360" for example? In "C360-C120" and "C240-C360" and I want to sum "C360"?

Comment: In this case is better to use `str_extract` as proposed by @zephryl adjusting the pattern argument accordingly.